# Did Eminem actually compose the song "Stronger Than I was"?

Tags: rap, hip-hop, production, eminem

About this song by Eminem, [*Stronger Than I Was*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZtzWLoS60w), Wikipedia shows Luis Resto and Eminem both as producers. My concern is that since the song contains very less rap portion did Luis composed most of the song?

As far as I knew Eminem didn't know technical music like keyboards etc.

Comment: He could have done something as simple as creating a drum pattern or two to get producer credit.

Comment: Like that time he took Aerosmith's Dream On...

Comment: @DJAftershock But this song is quite different. In 'Sing For The Moment' Eminem didn't _sing_. In this song he is _singing_ and his delivery is so good that it surpasses even professional singers.

Comment: @Bebs I somewhat agree with your answer. I remember Skylar Grey saying in an interview that Eminem is very good at mixing. +1 :-) P.S: But I think only Eminem or his colleges can tell the exact -- we can only speculate.

Comment: @user31782, don't forget to accept if the answer is OK for you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've found, Eminem (or Mathers) is credited on this song as **Writer** and **Producer**.

From [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/en/artist/38661-Eminem) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem):

> Eminem is an American rapper, **record producer**.

Also, about his own producing style:

> Eminem is considered **unusual in structuring his songs around the lyrics**, rather than writing to beats. (...) After **doing little production on Relapse and Recovery**, **Eminem produced a significant portion of The Marshall Mathers LP 2**.

He said about producing his own music,

> "Sometimes, I may get something in my head, like an **idea** or the **mood of something** that I would want, and I'm not always gonna get that by going through different tracks that other people have made. They don't know what's in my head. I think maybe it helps, a little bit, with diversity, the sound of it, but also, **I would get something in my head and want to be able to lay down that idea from scratch**."

Here is a [list of his work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem_production_discography) as a producer.

---

You can also note that a [record producer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_producer) may have different roles in the project *other that music instruments, hardware or software work*:

- gathering musical ideas
- collaborate with the artists to select cover tunes or original songs by the artist/group
- work with artists and help them to improve their songs
- coaching
- supervising the entire process
- gathering the staff (audio engineers, studio musicians...)
- etc...

So one can be a successful producer without knowing any knowledge in music theory or in how to play any instrument.